# jQuery animate to back to class specified values

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Animating verious elements with jQuery in one way is easy and works perfect however..

I did specify the origin positions from various naturs like width, position, margin etc. in the CSS with classes and ids. Now I have to reverse all my changes at some point, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this...

Some of the animations look like this

```
var topList = $("#topList");
$("#topList").css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: topList.offset().top,
    right: topList.offset().left,
}).animate({left:'-200%'}, 1000);

$("main").animate({height:'200px'}, 1000);
$("main h1").animate({'margin-top':'20px'}, 1000);

$("#submitNewInput").animate({width:'400px'}, 700);
$("#alias").css('display', 'inline').animate({width:'200px'}, 1000);
```

Now here are some of the css values

```
#topList {
    /* is just a normal with no attribute at all */
}
main {
    height: 260px;
}
h1 {
    /* no margin value */
}
```

**How would I reverse them?**

Something to keep in mind as well is that some values are kind of wired, like the default `h1` margin from chrome. I see that I could set and copy all the values in css and jquery alike but that would mean to make eventual changes always two times (kinda risky IMO)

I do not need any browser compatibility, chrome 48 is fine

Comment: You could clone elements then have jQuery transition to the cloned elements properties

Comment: @MarkEriksson to be more precies: have `visibility: hidden` clones and then animate them as `fixed` to there copys (with `topoffset` etc.), then remove the custom values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it by saving value as `data-` attribute in the element

Animate

```
links.attr("data-margin", links.css("marginLeft"));
links.animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 800);

chart.attr("data-margin", chart.css("marginTop"));
chart.animate({'margin-top':'0'}, 800);
```

Reverse

```
links.animate({'margin-left': links.attr("data-margin")}, 800);
chart.animate({'margin-top': chart.attr("data-margin")}, 800);
```

Answer (score 0):

> the below code will reverse the animation

```
    var topList = $("#topList");
    $("#topList").css({
     position: 'fixed',
     top: topList.offset().top,
     right: topList.offset().left,
    }).animate({left:'-200%'}, 1000,function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'200%'},1000);});
```

> pass callback function to animaton
>
> > also check this 
> >          [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naumanahmad/fb89w4du/) out